# stringbuilder as out parameter

Tags: c#, c++, stringbuilder

```
extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport)
bool FillString(LPWSTR OutName)
{
    LPWSTR out = L"TheName\0";
    int len = wcslen(out);
    memcpy(
                OutName,
                out,
                len * sizeof(wchar_t));
    return true;
}
```

That is function in my c/c++ dll, the following is my call from c#...

```
[DllImport(@"My.dll", EntryPoint = "FillString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool MyFunction([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder Name);

var fromdll = new StringBuilder(64); 
// I do not know length of out string (Name), but it is null terminated

bool IsFilled = MyFunction(fromdll);

Console.WriteLine(fromdll);
```

The output is

> TheName???

Can anyone help me to get the output...?

> TheName

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use e.g. [`wcscpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscpy)?

Comment: StringBuilder is mutable, but here is cast to C string, then nothing positive happens.

Comment: Seems like you are copying wcslen characters, without \0. Try to copy `(len+1) * sizeof(wchar_t)` characters.

Comment: No reason I never used wcscpy, I just never heard of it, I will look into it for better than memcpy. Anyway, your suggestion solved my issue, and I am grateful for such a swift response. Thank you.

Comment: The function is not only wrong but also very dangerous.  It requires an extra *bufferSize* argument so it cannot corrupt memory.  Copy the string with `wcscpy_s()`.  Pass fromdll.Capacity.

Comment: For the record, the string filling the buffer will never even come close to 64 chars, I wrote the code just as a simple example so as not to obscure my actual problem. I will examine more secure function for the copy. Thank you all for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy one more character. `'\0'` is called string terminator. Without it C, C++ and PInvoke in .NET do not recognize end of string. If you are copying `wcslen` characters, zero is not copied. There are many solutions:

1. Use mentioned [wcscpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscpy) to copy string with \0
2. Copy one more
   character with `memcpy(OutName, out, (len + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t))`.

Moreover, it's a good idea to pass buffer (StringBuilder) size. C/C++ lets you write outside variable boudaries. This size enables to avoid that.

Comment: I never realized there were multiple comments above, this answer solved my direct issue. Thanks.